# Toggle value is not updating

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a toggle which if you change its value from false -> true, a modal will popup and ask you to log in. If login is successful the toggle value should remain True. If something go wrong with the login process (invalid credentials) the Toggle should go back to False.

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, $http, $ionicModal, $timeout, $state, md5) {

$scope.invertToggle = function () {
  $localStorage.value = !$localStorage.value;
  $scope.value = $localStorage.value;
  console.log("Toggle New Value = " + $scope.value);
}

$scope.setToggleTrue = function() {
  $localStorage.value = true;
  $scope.value = true;
  console.log("Toggle New Value = " + $scope.value);
}

$scope.setToggleFalse = function() {
  $localStorage.value = false;
  $scope.value = false;
  console.log("Toggle New Value = " + $scope.value);
}

 $scope.change = function() {

  $scope.invertToggle();

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  }, {
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    backdropClickToClose: false,
    hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
    focusFirstInput: true
  });


  if ($localStorage.value == true) {
   console.log("Modal will pop up");
   $scope.modal.show();
  } else {
    console.log("Unregister device");
  }
 }
$scope.submit = function() {


    if (res.data != "Wrong Credentials") {
      //We are not changing the toggle value here since login is ok
    }
    else{
      $scope.setToggleFalse(); //login details were invalid, so we are setting toggle to false
    }

   })

   .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);

    if (error.statusText == ""){
      $scope.response = "Unexpected error. Make sure WiFi is on."
    }
    else {
      $scope.response = "Error - "+error.status + " ("+error.statusText+")";
    }
    $scope.setToggleFalse(); //Unfortunatly here, an error occured so, we setting the Toggle back to False, just to be safe   
   })

   .finally(function() {
    console.log("Finally Function");
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.modal.hide(); // we are hiding the modal, so the user returns to the previous page
        $scope.$apply(function () { //I found somewhere $apply can do the trick but no luck
          $scope.value = false; // Here I manually set the variable to false but again the toggle is still on on the page.
        });
     }, 3000);

   });
 };
});
```

Here is the toggle html:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="value"  ng-checked="value" ng-change="change()"toggle-class="toggle-royal">Register Device</ion-toggle>
```

How can I auto refresh the variable on the page? I tried by setting cache to false, again no luck. The code is messy I know, but Once everything is in a working state, I will use henry the hoover to clean up the dirt. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try give the modal access the original controller's scope by passing in the scope parameter:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  }, {
    scope: $scope,  /// GIVE THE MODAL ACCESS TO PARENT SCOPE
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    backdropClickToClose: false,
    hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
    focusFirstInput: true
  });
```

Comment: Now im not able to use $scope.modal.hide(); I was facing that before and I solved it by removing the line you mentioned.

Comment: I managed to do exactly what I was looking for, but I haven't use any modals. I just created a new page, which I'm fetching the details I need from one page to another